# SQL find record with null and prev record not null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

Here i want result for customerID which have offerdate null and prevoius offer date not be null for same CID.

CURRENT Result :

```
            CID             orderDate           offerdate1   
            1               2015-08-11          2014-08-10
            1               2015-08-12          2014-08-11
            1               2015-08-12          NULL                
            2               2016-08-13          2015-08-11
            2               2016-08-13          2015-08-12
            3               2016-08-13          NULL
            4               2016-01-12          2016-01-12
            4               2016-02-12          Null
```

Expected Result :

```
            CID             orderDate           offerdate1   
            1               2015-08-12          2014-08-11
            1               2015-08-12          NULL
            4               2016-01-12          2016-01-12
            4               2016-02-12          Null
```

eg. for CID='1'
recent order date is 2015-08-12 and offer date is NULL.
but same CID having offerdate on prevoius orderdate.i.e.'2014-08-11'
So i want only records which offerdate is null and but shaving offerdate on previous orderdate.

Comment: Did you try anything yet? I don't think this site is for getting work done. Please show us what you have tried and what is the problems you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `SQL Server 2008` and later you can use:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [CID] INT
   ,[orderDate] DATE
   ,[offerdate1] DATE
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([CID], [orderDate], [offerdate1])
VALUES (1, '2015-08-11', '2014-08-10')
      ,(1, '2015-08-12', '2014-08-11')
      ,(1, '2015-08-12', NULL)
      ,(2, '2016-08-13', '2015-08-11')
      ,(2, '2016-08-13', '2015-08-12')
      ,(3, '2016-08-13', NULL)
      ,(4, '2016-01-12', '2016-01-12')
      ,(4, '2016-02-12', NULL);

WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [CID] ORDER BY [orderDate], [offerdate1] DESC) AS [RowID]
    FROM @DataSource
),
FinalDataSource AS
(
    SELECT DS1.[CID]
          ,DS1.[orderDate]
          ,DS1.[offerdate1]
          ,DS2.[CID] AS DS2_CID
          ,DS2.[orderDate] AS DS2_orderDate
          ,DS2.[offerdate1] AS DS2_offerdate1
    FROM DataSource DS1
    INNER JOIN DataSource DS2
        ON DS1.[CID] = DS2.[CID]
        AND DS1.[RowID] = DS2.[RowID] + 1
    WHERE DS1.[offerdate1] IS NULL
)
SELECT [CID]
      ,[orderDate]
      ,[offerdate1]
FROM FinalDataSource
UNION ALL
SELECT [DS2_CID]
      ,[DS2_orderDate]
      ,[DS2_offerdate1]
FROM FinalDataSource;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try window functions. `LAG(offerdate)` allows you to detect `NULL` rows where the previous is `NOT NULL` and `LEAD(offerdate), LEAD(orderdate)` let you detect the row preceding the NULL row.

```
select t.cid, t.orderdate, t.offerdate
from
(
  select *, 
         lag(offerdate) over (partition by cid order by orderdate, coalesce(offerdate,getdate())) offerlag,
         lead(offerdate) over (partition by cid order by orderdate, coalesce(offerdate,getdate())) offerlead,
         lead(orderdate) over (partition by cid order by orderdate, coalesce(offerdate,getdate())) orderlead
  from your_table
) t
where t.offerdate is null and t.offerlag is not null or -- NULL row detection
      t.offerdate is not null and t.offerlead is null and t.orderlead is not  null -- row preceding the NULL row detection
order by cid, orderdate, coalesce(offerdate,getdate())
```

[demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=7e93437f22339f2b4e2d998b53b30e30)

My solution assumes that there is no date following the today's date. If it is not true, then replace `getdate()` in my solution by some date larger than any date in database. For example, if you have also the today's date in the database (and no future dates) then you can replace `getDate()` by `dateadd(day, 1, getDate())`

Answer (score 0):

I have inserted values from "CURRENT Result :" into a new table t1 and below you have expected results:

```
select * from (
    select * from t1 where cid in
        (select cid from t1 where offerdate1 is null group by cid) and cid  not in
        (select cid from (  
        (select cid, min(offerdate1), max(offerdate1) from t1 having min(offerdate1) is null group by cid))) and offerdate1 is null
    union all
    select cid, min(orderdate), max(offerdate1) from (
        select * from t1 where cid in
        (select cid from t1 where offerdate1 is null group by cid) and cid  not in
        (select cid from (  
        (select cid, min(offerdate1), max(offerdate1) from t1 having min(offerdate1) is null group by cid)))) group by cid
) order by cid, orderdate;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        select  b.cid,
                b.orderDate,
                b.offerdate1  
        from 
        (
        select  cid,
                orderDate,
                offerdate1  
        From #temp  A
        where A.offerdate1 is null 
        and exists ( 
        select 1 from #temp B 
        where   a.cid = b.cid 
        and     B.offerdate1 is not  null  )

        ) a 
        inner join #temp b
        on a.cid = b.cid
        where b.offerdate1 = (select max(offerdate1) from  #temp C where c.cid = a.cid )

        union all

        select  cid,
                orderDate,
                offerdate1  
        From #temp  A
        where A.offerdate1 is null 
        and exists ( 
        select 1 from #temp B 
        where   a.cid = b.cid 
        and     B.offerdate1 is not  null  )
        order by cid,offerdate1 desc
```